# JQUERY data tables installation

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, datatables

I want to use the datatables jquery plugin for my project. I'm doing the project on cakePHP. I can't seem to get datatables running. I'm not quite sure if my code is right. Also I have added the css file and the two JS files in my directory under Webroot/css and Webroot/js.
Can someone help me please?

My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/DataTables-1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/DataTables-1.10.0/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="/DataTables-1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#callTable').DataTable();
} )
</head>

<?php
$usertype=$this->SESSION->read('User.usertype');
if($usertype=="admin")
    echo $this->element('setTopNavigation');
else
    echo $this->element('setTopNavigationStaff');

//var_dump($calls);
?>
<div class="callsIndex">
    <h2><?php echo __('Call Details'); ?>   </h2>
    <div class="bottomButtonnew"><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add Calls'), array('action' => 'add')); ?></div>
    <table id="callTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Time'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Comments'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Next Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Customer Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Company Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Employee Name'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __(''); ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($calls as $call): ?>

        <?php
            $class ='';
            if($call['Call']['next_call_date']==date('Y-m-d')){
                $class = ' class="call_for_today"';
            }
        ?>
            <tr<?php echo $class; ?>>
                 <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($call['Call']['call_date'])); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_time']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['comments']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($call['Call']['next_call_date'])); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Customers']['customer_name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $call['Customers']['id'])); ?>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Companies']['company_name'], array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'view', $call['Companies']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Employees']['employee_name'], array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'view', $call['Employees']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td class="actions">
                   <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $call['Call']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <p>
        <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
            'format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total')
        ));
        ?>  </p>
    <div class="paging">
        <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
        ?>
    </div>
    <br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

**1)** Add `document.ready` inside `script` tag and put semicolon (;) at the end of `document.ready`

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#callTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

**2)** And datatable work with table structure which has header enclosed in `<thead></thead>` tag and row enclosed inside `<tbody></tbody>` like below
:

```
<table id="callTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
           <thead>
            <tr>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Call Time'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Comments'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Next Call Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Customer Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Company Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Employee Name'); ?></th>
            <th class="actions"><?php echo __(''); ?></th>
        </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($calls as $call): ?>

        <?php
            $class ='';
            if($call['Call']['next_call_date']==date('Y-m-d')){
                $class = ' class="call_for_today"';
            }
        ?>
            <tr<?php echo $class; ?>>
                 <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($call['Call']['call_date'])); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['call_time']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo h($call['Call']['comments']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($call['Call']['next_call_date'])); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Customers']['customer_name'], array('controller' => 'customers', 'action' => 'view', $call['Customers']['id'])); ?>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Companies']['company_name'], array('controller' => 'companies', 'action' => 'view', $call['Companies']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($call['Employees']['employee_name'], array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'view', $call['Employees']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td class="actions">
                   <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $call['Call']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I made the changes you pointed out but the search bar doesn't appear on the page.

Comment: call datatable like this '$('#callTable').DataTable({"bFilter": true});'

Answer (score 0):

Your `$(document).ready` handler needs to be placed inside a `<script>` tag